# (U+0007 : BELL [BEL]) displays and then doesn't

Tags: bug, unicode

The first character of this text is U+0007 : BELL [BEL]. It shows up in the preview of questions but not on the actual post.

It doesn't show up on [google search](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk018Yxz2re5LkIspArLcO0VOXz_cmA%3A1598287198564&ei=Xu1DX4CUItKy9QOszKGYAw&q=%20%07&oq=%20%07&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIECCMQJzIECCMQJzIECCMQJzIECCMQJzIECCMQJzIECCMQJzIECCMQJzIECCMQJzIECCMQJzIECCMQJ1BvWG9g_gNoAHAAeACAAaUCiAG9A5IBBTAuMS4xmAEAoAECoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdperABCg&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiAu-Dlo7TrAhVSWX0KHSxmCDMQ4dUDCAw&uact=5) either.

After editing post the character completely disappears from the edit body as well.

Why does the control character show up in the preview of the question as a telephone icon while editing and posting? Why does it disappear completely while trying to edit again? If it's being filtered out, why is it not filtered out on the front end while creating the post itself?

Thanks! :)

*Here is a screenshot

[image: Character not showing]

Comment: This does not seem to be specific to the Stackoverflow website, see for example this C# answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59236556/1781026

Comment: U+0007 or ASCII 0007 should indeed not show up. It should instead ring an electronic bell, if one's attached to your computer. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character). The only bug here seems inconsistent behavior between the preview window and the body. If you want a telephone emoji, use a telephone emoji, and generally avoid control characters in question titles/bodies, except tab, CR and LF.

Comment: @ErikA That makes sense. I just wanted to clarify that while creating the question it shows up on both the preview window and the body as telephone icon, just not on the actual post.
I wasn't trying to use it as a telephone emoji, just ran into this behavior erratically.

Comment: Doesn't render for me at all. (Linux Mint 20, latest FF)

Comment: I just see the hex box while editing (both textarea and preview), but not in the rendered post. Firefox Nightly 82.0a1, Linux 5.8.3.arch1-1, Gnome 1:3.36.5-1.