# Migrating question from Stack Overflow to Meta

Tags: support, migration

I had a question posted on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63565232/u0007-bell-bel-displays-nd-then-doesnt?noredirect=1#comment112406271_63565232) and was told it was more appropriate for Meta. Is there a way that the question can be moved to meta without having to [repost](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400649/u0007-bell-bel-displays-and-then-doesnt)?

For now, I have manually copied over the [question on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400649/u0007-bell-bel-displays-and-then-doesnt)
[The question was originally on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63565232/u0007-bell-bel-displays-nd-then-doesnt?noredirect=1#comment112406271_63565232)

Comment: Since you already copied it, don't forget to delete the original question. Usually, you would close the question as "belongs to another site".

Comment: Yes, I flagged it for moderation and requested to close it.

Comment: You shouldn't flag for moderator attention. Flag for: "Needs improvement" > "a community specific reason" > "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network" > "belongs on meta.stackoverflow.com"

Comment: @Sarwagya you don't flag anything.  Just delete it in this case since you migrated it yourself manually.  There bottom left of your question (above the comments) there is a link that says "Delete".  Click it.  Then click yes on the dialog that pops up.

Comment: @BDL Thanks, I have retracted the flag and flagged it appropriately for "belongs on meta.stackoverflow.com".

Comment: You've already posted a new question on meta, so there is no need to merge the other question as well.